# the Value not supported error when i used the element.mul(int) function with JPBC

Tags: java

sorry for my broken English first....

when i run my code in the following, it always give me the error msg

my java code is simple like:

```
TypeACurveGenerator pg = new TypeACurveGenerator(160,512);
PairingParameters typeAParams = pg.generate();
PairingFactory.getInstance().setUsePBCWhenPossible(true);
Pairing p=PairingFactory.getPairing(typeAParams);
Element e=p.getG1().newElement().setToOne();
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i+" "+e+" "+e.mul(i));
}
```

this code just generate a element and multiply between element and an int.

and the compiler give me the output:

```
0 0,0,1 0,0,1
1 0,0,1 0,0,1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value not supported.
at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.field.curve.CurveElement.set(CurveElement.java:73)
at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.field.curve.CurveElement.set(CurveElement.java:12)
at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.field.base.AbstractElement.mul(AbstractElement.java:82)
at test.main(test.java:27) //the line: System.out.println(i+" "+e+" "+e.mul(i));
```

I really have no idea what this error message means.

It seems like that when the int is bigger than 1, then the program gets the error.

And what I am also confused about is that the result is correct when element multiply 1 is equal to multiply 0?

I added all the *.jar files of JPBC into my project's classpath 
[image: jar of JPBC in detail]

and I used the win10 with Eclipse.
Version: jpbc-2.0.0, Java-1.8.0_65.

thanks for your reply(*´∀`)~♡

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely familiar with PBC and have only a basic knowledge of elliptic curves.  I'm assuming what you're trying to do is to take a point *p* on an elliptic curve and print out 0, *p*, *p + p*, *p + p + p* and so on.  (I've used additive notation for the group operation here; using multiplicative notation instead, you would be attempting to compute 1, *p*, *p*<sup>2</sup>, *p*<sup>3</sup>,...)

For some reason, `CurveElement` doesn't override `mul(int)`, so the base class `AbstractElement` attempts to convert the given integer into a group element and perform the group operation with your element `e` and whatever element this integer gets converted into.  JPBC only supports converting the integers 0 and 1 to group elements, and both of them get converted to the identity element.

However, `CurveElement` does support `mul(BigInteger)`, and this does do the repeated group operation you appear to be looking for.  So, instead of writing

```
System.out.println(i+" "+e+" "+e.mul(i));
```

you can try writing

```
System.out.println(i+" "+e+" "+e.mul(BigInteger.valueOf(i)));
```

I made this change to your code and it outputted the following:

```
0 0,0,1 0,0,1
1 0,0,1 0,0,1
2 0,0,1 0,0,1
3 0,0,1 0,0,1
4 0,0,1 0,0,1
```

Of course, all of the values are the same because your element `e` is the identity.